# Yii2 ckeditor How to hide options in the header like image upload , help etc

Tags: yii2, ckeditor

I have ckeditor in my yii2 project.like

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'description')->widget(CKEditor::className(), [
        'options' => ['rows' => 6],
        'preset' => 'basic',
        'clientOptions' => [
        'buttonsHide' => ['image','file','about','link','unlink','anchor'],
    ]
]) ?>
```

I am trying to hide the image upload , help , link , unlink and anchor.i tried the above code.but it didn't worked for me.It showing all options there.hides nothing.How can i remove them.Thanks in advance.

```
i am using "2amigos/yii2-ckeditor-widget" : "*"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
'clientOptions' => [
    'removeButtons' => 'Image,File,About,Link,Unlink,Anchor',
]
```